# Is ノーマル customary in reference to being straight

Tags: word-choice

I was recently watching an anime and one of the character, in reference to him being straight, said:

> 僕はノーマルなので

(in case I misunderstood, this is from Eromanga Sensei, ep09 at around the 6:30 mark)

I got curious and tried to research whether this was the usual way to state that someone is straight but couldn't find anything. I know ストレート can be used in this context.

Did I completely misunderstood what's being said?
If not, is this commonplace? Is it considered acceptable or rude?
If this is considered rude, what would be the acceptable way so saying I'm straight.

Edit:
For context, it's been an on-going thing on the show that Kunimitsu (the character I quoted above) thinks the main character (Masamune) is gay. During the scene I'm referencing, Kunimitsu is offered to share a bedroom with the main character to which he object.

Comment: It might be useful to have more background information on this, can you give us the line that was said before what you quoted?.

Comment: Of course, editing my question to add context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ノーマル is the simplest and the most common word to refer to this, and there is usually no derogatory implication at all. ノンケ is the second most common word, but it's slangy and argot-like. Although some people who dislike ノーマル may use ストレート intentionally, ストレート is rare in Japanese.

If you don't like ノーマル, there are ways to refer to this more euphemistically:

- 僕はそっちじゃない (literally "I'm not on that side")
- 僕はそっち系ではない
- 僕にその気【け】はない

Comment: Yeah I had heard those other ones before. I was just the first time I heard it said this way, or at least picked up on it, and was curious to know whether this was common and socially acceptable and couldn't find much on that except ストレート. Anyway, thanks for your explanation.