# What's the most common/natural way to say someone is straight/heterosexual?

Tags: word-choice, words

I know a zillion ways to refer to how people are homosexual, but I just realized I'm not sure of any common ways to refer to someone being straight. All I've heard and know is basically how to say one is "not homosexual".

If possible, I'd like the most casual/common term used.

Edit: From this jdrama I'm watching, I'm inclined to believe that heterosexuality is so normalized, that there's no common way to refer to it outside of the formal 異性愛者｛いせいあいしゃ｝. Just like how, in English, there's a zillion words for handicapped people, but no common words for people without any handicaps. (e.g. "paraplegic" for not having functioning legs, but no word for having functioning legs, because having functioning legs is just so normalized)

Comment: *zillion*??  Perhaps you really mean a few: like three or four, possibly a bit more.

Comment: Related: [Is ノーマル customary in reference to being straight](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/78582/5010) (I wrote this answer in 2020, but ストレート might have become a bit more common recently)

Answer (score 2):

After all, at least traditionally, heterosexuality is the norm, there is not much need to mention it. Accordingly, there are not a lot of words for heterosexuality. Even today, people don't really need to express someone is heterosexual except for denying homosexuality, which should be why what you've heard is 'not homosexual'. (I believe it's more or less similar in English)

[ノンケ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8E%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B1) is a casual word/slang meaning heterosexual people. It is common esp. in contexts of BL manga or other subcultural fields. It derives from 'non' + ケ (気: その気{け}がある means 'having homosexual tendencies'). E.g., 彼はノンケだ (he is heterosexual) or ノンケの人 (heterosexual person) are possible. Note this is chiefly used by homosexuals as noted in the linked Wikipedia article.

Another word is simply ヘテロ abbreviated in the same way as ホモ derives from homosexual.